# Best proof of some theorems in calculus

Tags: calculus, soft-question, proof-writing

I would like to choose (among the miriads of proofs) a well-structured, elegant, neat, clear proof of

- the first fundamental theorem of calculus;
- the second fundamental theorem of calculus;
- the mean value theorem;
- the intermediate value theorem;
- Weierstrass theorem;
- Rolles' theorem.

Which book (I can choose among Spivak, Stewart, Apostol and a few other ones) offers the well-structured, elegant, neat, clear proof of them (NB you can pick a different book for every theorem if it is the case)?

Added: Do you think that Apostol's proofs are elegant and rigorous?

Answer (score 2):

In my humble opinion, Rudin's "Principles of Mathematical Analysis" is what you are seeking.

Comment: I see. What do you think about Apostol's proofs?